# How is 'coarse' translated in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

I'm looking for a Spanish translation of **coarse** under this meaning: consisting of large grains or particles. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article about mineral grains](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grano_(mineral)) uses *de grano grueso*:

> Existen rocas *de grano* fino, medio y *grueso*

'grueso' has the same roots as the English word ['gross'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gross), according to [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/grueso):

> grueso, sa
>
> Del lat. tardío grossus.
>
> 1. adj. Corpulento y abultado.
> 2. adj. Que excede de lo regular.

One of the many definitions of ['grano'](https://dle.rae.es/grueso):

> 4. m. Porción o parte menuda de algo de forma similar a la semilla de los cereales. Grano de arena, de incienso.

Literally translated it would mean 'of/with gross grains/granularity'; I'll defer to the expertise of native speakers that there is no *single* word that exactly matches your translation request.

Comment: As in this example, you normally need to say "**de grano** grueso", as "grueso" itself does not mean what the OP wants ("consisting of large grains or particles"). It just means "large". It is probably still the best option, as I do not think there is a Spanish word that means "consisting of large grains or particles".

Comment: Thanks. In English, I'd always use 'coarse-*grained*', hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adjective “***[basto](https://dle.rae.es/basto)***”:

```
Grosero, tosco, sin pulimento.
```

as in *lija basta* (coarse sandpaper) or *tejido basto* (coarse fabric).